# Strange rendering issue in Chrome, Opera and Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, opera

Folks I'm baffled. I've produced an HTML page which uses CSS animation and some very basic Javascript. Although I'm sure I haven't done it the best/most efficient way (still a bit new to this), it works enough for me to be happy with it, but when running in Chrome, Safari or Opera I run into an intermittent issue with how some elements are rendered.

Live example: http://careers.dept.shef.ac.uk/MOOCs/STAR/

Navigate down to "Problem Solving Skills", then from there navigate to either "Communication skills" or "Leadership skills". The navigation buttons that were at the bottom Problem Solving Skills are still visible. But they're not really there... if I hit Ctrl+A they disappear. You can't click on them, they're just left there.

I've tried this on a few PCs and had the same issue. Sometimes it doesn't happen at all. It doesn't seem to happen on IE or Firefox. Could it be to do with how these browsers render elements and how they process opacity?

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: here's a screen grab: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPtGQ.png

Comment: After clicking 'Communication Skills', the buttons are still clickable for me? I've tested in Chrome PC, Chrome and Opera on a MAC. It happens without fail. Which exact buttons are you expecting to disappear?

Comment: Hi Tony, are you seeing two rows of buttons? I've added a screen grab to the original question to show what I mean.

Comment: I'm on Chrome and FreeBSD but don't see two sets either.

Comment: ...starting to wonder if this could be a hardware issue...would that be possible? Thanks for your comments so far.

Comment: Thanks for the screen grab. As far as i'm aware this can't be a hardware issue, but more of an issue with the browser engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a long shot, but you have malformed HTML on those buttons, trying fixing that and see what happens:

```
<p class="btnText">Communication skills</p class="btnText">
```

should be:

```
<p class="btnText">Communication skills</p>
```

**Edit**

Okay, try adding this style to .example2:

```
height: 100%;
```

and change overflow to:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to have made a difference but thanks for spotting that! Think I aught to stand in the corner and think about what I've done there...

Comment: Thanks that definitely works as a patch up - it covers the problem and with a bit of adjusting should fit. My only concern is if someone is viewing on a particularly short screen they might lose the bottom of the page.

if I add `overflow:scroll;` instead that might work... with a few other adjustments.

Ideally I'd rather make those buttons actually disappear, but if that's just not possible this will do the trick!